# От()чего в значении "из-за чего" - слитно или раздельно

Tags: орфография

В правилах везде сказано, что "отчего" пишется слитно, если можно заменить это слово на "почему". А если заменяется по значению на "из-за чего", например:

"Это было так от()того что..."

Слитно или раздельно? Как-то я запуталась

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь, вероятно, слитно. По тому же правилу и тем же соображениям. И не забудьте запятую перед "что".

***Это было так оттого, что...***

Но вообще-то, лучше бы всю фразу целиком. Бывают казусы, когда придаточное заставляет использовать другое написание.

Comment: Например:

Этот день выдался не то чтобы жарким, но каким-то душным, ночью прошел дождь, а тут солнце выглянуло и принялось высушивать лужи, отчего было очень влажно, прямо не продохнуть.

Comment: Или

Северная кровь наделила *** серо-голубыми глазами и светлой кожей, отчего деревенские сравнивали его с мертвяком-утопленником.

Comment: Вы же спрашивали про предложения с "оттого". С Вашими примерами вопросов нет, там слитно. Естественную фразу с раздельным написанием "от чего" придумать довольно сложно. А вот с "от того" случается.

Comment: От чего ты отталкиваешься?

Comment: Ларf, ну мы же говорили о фразе, начинающейся с "Это было так оттого, что...". Ну и о примерах двумя комментариями выше. 
А так-то придумать можно многое. Вы вот попробуйте придумать так, чтобы это был союз (или союзное слово) в придаточном - тогда будет интересно.

Comment: *Это было именно то, от чего я окончательно растерялся*

*Покажи мне, от чего ты отталкиваешься* (пример Ларf)

Comment: Я знаю, от чего ты отталкиваешься.

Comment: Н-да... Что-то не могу я сформулировать, что тут не так, хотя яно это не тот случай. Пока беру тайм-аут.
Кстати, тут-то может быть разное написание - от смысла.

Comment: Конечно, разное.